# Sending XML messages--Database problem?

Tags: php, sql, xml, xampp

i have created a form in php that gets some data from the user.Then, as i press the btn "send",the form send xml messages to three other php files.this is the view when i press the send button.

[image]

i think there i a problem with my database!Please help(i m using xampp and i have uploaded my database in xampp!thanks)

Comment: What does line 22 of the process.php file do?  Are there parameters you are passing to a function at that location?  If so, what are their values.

Comment: this it line 22:$xmlData=xml2ary(file_get_contents($__XML_NAME));

Comment: i m so sorry if my answer is not understandable,but this is the first time i work with php ,just for my universitys exercise!thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as Colin Fine said, it cannot find XMLs/orders/1292595112.xml.

Second, connection to MySQL database failed, because you proviede wrong username, password or location.

The rest of errors are most possibly just a chain reaction to a failed db connection (instead of resource, mysql_connect() returned false and that caused errors saying 'expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given').

So first I'd look into database connection settings and then deal with the rest ...

Answer (score 0):

It is telling you that it cannot find the file XMLs/orders/1292595112.xml